# Session Management in Jaggery.js

Tags: mysql, jaggery-js

I am trying to get some hands on ***Jaggery frameworks modules*** and i am facing problems in `managing the sessions.`
For eg Lets say the user is logging in and then logging out, but even after that when he presses the back button in browser in takes back the user to inner pages.

Here I am destroying the session on clicking Logout like `session.invalidate();`
but then to the user can traverse back.

Does anyone know how to solve this and manage sessions.
Thanks !

Comment: [check this](http://madhukaudantha.blogspot.com.tr/2012/08/using-mysql-in-jaggeryjs.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To connect Jaggery to MySQL, you need to [*download*](http://www.4shared.com/file/ELPzjU5j/mysql_connector_java_5110_bin_.html?) JDBC driver jar to `<jaggery>\carbon\repository\components\dropins\` directory. 
In MySQL, create new database ***sodb*** by typing: `mysql> create database sodb`. 
 
the example below shows how to create table, insert data in MySQL and view the data using Jaggery.

1. Create folder ***sodbmysql*** in /apps/
2. Create ***sodb.jag*** file in the sodbmysql folder then add this code in the file:

   ```
    <%
   var query1 = "CREATE TABLE example(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(id), name VARCHAR(30), age INT);";
   config = {};
   var db = new Database("jdbc:mysql://<mysql host>:<port>/<database>", "<mysql_username>", "<mysql_password>", config);
   try{db.query(query1); print('Created the table');}
   catch(e){print(e.toString());}
   finally{db.close();}
   %>
   ```
3. Start Jaggery server and go to: `localhost:9763/sodbmysql/sodb.jag`. 
   Go to MySQL console> database sodb and enter this to view the table: `mysql> show tables;`. 
   To insert the data from Jaggery application, change query to insert data to table:
   `var query1 ="INSERT INTO example (name, age) VALUES('Jad','34');"`. 
    
   To print in jaggery page, use:

   ```
   var query1 = "SELECT * FROM example;"
   ```

   or:

   ```
   var results = db.query(query3);
   print(results);
   ```

** For more information, check this [*link*](http://cs263-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/jaggery.html).

Comment: but in this we created a separate application in /apps/ folder ;   but i already have a web-app in which i want to use database so how can i do it without creating a different app ?? and also  if you can help me how to access the database in jaggery for login page or register page just an example.

Comment: :Hey did you find anything related to my query?

Comment: @AvnishMehta, for the App you have, create the file and write the code in the existing folder. As for the rest of your comment, you should post new question **after searching** in the web and the other sources.

Comment: How does this answer relates to the question here?

Comment: @Dilshan in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26189576/session-management-in-jaggery-js/26190024#comment41102590_26190024) way